# How can i split values with twig using filters

Tags: twig

I have a value inside {{ phone }} that i want to split to be formatted as a phone number with twig filters

Example; inside {{ phone }} = '20304050', i want the output to be: '20 30 40 50'.

I found this example :

```
{% set splitArray = "20304050"|split('', 2) %}
{% set formattedString = splitArray|join(' ') %}
```

But it doesn't work with my value inside the brackets {{ phone }}

Comment: You don't have to use the accolades inside a `{%` statement, the line should become `{% set split = phone|split(''), 2) %}`, which works fine as seen [here](https://twigfiddle.com/tzln0a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

```
{{ phone|split('', 2)|join(' ') }}
```